# Term for this diagram in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have objects $X$ and $Y$, and some set of morphisms $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$.

Now suppose there is a third object $Z$, and a morphism $f:X\to Z$, such that, for each $g\in \text{Hom}(X,Y)$ there is a $g_Z\in \text{Hom}(Z,Y)$ with $g=g_Z\circ f$.

Is there a name for this pair $(Z,f)$?

Comment: So basically you are saying that every morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ factors through $f:X\rightarrow Z$. This definition seems to depend only on $f$ and $Y$ but I don't know any reasonable name for such a thing.

Comment: I guess you could call $f$ a factoring map for $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 I looked it up and maybe  “factors through” is the term I’m looking for.

Comment: @user56834 Just note that usually "factors through" is most often used for a specific choice of $g$, rather than for every $g$ simultaneously.